# What is the time of the first RTO in the TCP protocol without knowing the RTT?

Tags: tcp, rtt

I know that 3 way handshake is used. But, the first time a connection is established and there is no RTT data, what is the expected time before sending another packet?

[image]

How does the client know how long to wait for the first confirmation? Is there any calculation or previous procedure?

PS: English is not my native language: :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before SYN-ACK is received from the destination, the socket is still in the SYN-SENT state. The timeout used and possible SYN retries depend on the *initial connection timeout*, not the retransmission timeout. The RTO is only used for an already established socket.

Comment: And this initial connection timeout is standard or is there any way to calculate it?

Comment: @toborochi That initial timeout is system/implementation specific. I'm not aware of any standard. There's no way to calculate it because you have no data.

Comment: Thanks dude. You will not have any link to know the value of each system/implementation or some kind of reference.?